# javascript function that accepts an object and returns the value of the title property from that object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a study item that states: Write a function bestShow that accepts an object and returns the value of the title property from that object.

Hint provided:
console.log(bestShow({ genre: 'comedy', title: 'Seinfeld' }));
//Should print: Seinfeld

I've tried so many different things. Here is one iteration, where I finally gave up.

```
function bestShow(genre, title)
{
this.genre =  genre;
this.title = title;
}
var show = new bestShow(‘comedy’, ‘Seinfeld’);
console.log(show.bestShow.title);
```

Comment: `function bestShow (obj) { return obj.title }`

Comment: Hint: Your assignment says nothing about using `new`. It says to return the value of a property on the object passed to your function.

Comment: you could call like this  `console.log(show.title);`

Answer (score 1):

This ES6 fat arrow function will do:

```
let title = (data) => data.title;
```

**Pre ES6 version**:

We will define a function, which accepts `{genre: "comedy", title: "Sienfeld"}` which is in-turn a valid JS object with properties `genre` and `title`. So all that is left there to do is to return the value of `title` property of our `data` parameter. Then we are just calling our function and using the result as an input for `console.log`.

```
function title(data) {
 return data.title;
}
console.log(title({ genre: 'comedy', title: 'Seinfeld' }));
```

Comment: While that may work, the "fat arrow function" is beyond my learning stage at this point. :)

Comment: @RebekahPaul I've updated my answer to include a version, which i think you can understand.

Comment: Thank you, Rajat. I appreciate all the hints but I think at this point I need to see it complete because I'm not getting it. :( None of the responses are including this which it needs to include: console.log(bestShow({ genre: 'comedy', title: 'Seinfeld' }));

Comment: @RebekahPaul I've included the console.log part. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Why all this!
Look it's so simple !

```
function bestShow(obj) {
    return obj.title; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
var bestShow = new Object();
    bestShow. genre = 'comedy';
    bestShow. title = 'Seinfeld';
console.log(bestShow.title);
```